# Error checking context is accessible: 'can't stat '.gvfs''. Please check permissions and try again

Tags: docker

I created a Dockerfile in my root.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04

MAINTAINER Bhim Singh <bhim3003@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get y install java

CMD echo hello
```

then i tried to run this command : `sudo docker  build -t bhim3003/myjava .`

I am recieving this error:

> " Error checking context is accessible: 'can't stat '.gvfs''. Please
>   check permissions and try again."

And docker image is not created. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this Dockerfile in your home directory? In case there are files which the current user can't access you will run into this error.

Comment: I am stuck with same error message. Using mingcw on Windows.

Comment: Why does docker look at other files in the directory? What reason does it have for this?

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue while working with boot2docker on Windows 7. However I was able to build it successfully after moving dockerfile outside home directory.

Comment: Same error, but on a Windows OS. This answer fixed it

Comment: Same error on ubuntu 14.04, moving to non-home directory worked

Comment: The same strategy works for the same issue in mac as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue is occurred because when we call docker build all files searched in working directory and as docker does not run with administrator privilege cannot access to some files and this error generated.

Solution:

- Move to directory which all user can accessed (for example: /c)
- Create new directory (sep)
- Create Dockerfile in new directory
- Run build

commands:

```
$ cd /c

$ mkdir sep

$ cd sep

$ touch Dockerfile

# vi Dockerfile

# docker build -t fahsep/debian
```